# Suppose $f,g$ are in $S_n$ and that $g$ is a transposition. Then $\text{cyc}(fg) = \text{cyc}(f) \pm 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]I am learning this lemma and need some clarification on an example in my notes. I thought I understood the lemma until the example below:

$$
f = (1538)(27)
$$

If $g=(57)$ then $fg = (152738)$.

I don't understand the composition of the function, I am unsure of how they got to one cycle in that order.

Comment: The number of cycles of f

Comment: Is there a way that I can add pictures? I have the notes and could copy and paste but I don't know how to format !

Comment: I have included the screen shot in the question if this is helpful.

Comment: I just don't understand how to calculate the composition of the permutation to be left with (152738)

Answer (score 2):

Let's get you started. Compute $(fg)(1) = f(g(1))$. Note that $g(1) = 1$, since $g$ only swaps $5$ and $7$. Also $f(1) = 5$, by definition of cycle notation; since $5$ appears to the right of $1$ in $f = (1 5 3 8)(2 7)$.

Now compute $(fg)(5)$ the same way. We have $g(5) = 7$, and $f(7) = 2$, so $(fg)(5) = f(g(5)) = 2$. So far, our cycle notation looks like $fg = (152\ldots$

Next, compute $(fg)(2)$, and keep going until you get to $1$ again. This forms a cycle in your cycle notation. If this cycle misses any numbers (e.g. $4$), then start the process again, this time starting from $4$. In this case, $(fg)(4) = 4$, since both $f$ and $g$ fix $4$. You don't need to include singleton cycles, since these are just identity permutations!

Good luck!

Comment: Omg thank you so much !!!!!! Life saver !!